# How do you dynamically edit robots.txt in a load balanced environment?

Tags: seo, load-balancing, robots.txt

Looks like we are going to have to start load balancing our webservers here soon.

We have a feature request to edit robots.txt dynamically which is not a problem for one host -- however once we get our load balancer up and going -- it sounds like I will have to scp the file over to the other host(s).

This sounds extremely 'bad'. How would you handle this situation?

I already let the client edit the meta tag 'robots' which (imo) should effectively do the same thing as he wants from the robots.txt editing but I really don't know that much about SEO.

Maybe there is a completely different way of handling this?

**UPDATE**

looks like we will store it in s3 for now and memcache it frontside...

**HOW WE ARE DOING IT NOW**

so we are using merb..I mapped a route to our robots.txt like so:

```
match('/robots.txt').to(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'robots')
```

then that relevant code looks like this:

```
def robots
  @cache = MMCACHE.clone
  begin
    robot = @cache.get("/robots/robots.txt")
  rescue
    robot = S3.get('robots', "robots.txt")
    @cache.set("/robots/robots.txt", robot, 0)
  end
  @cache.quit
  return robot
end
```

Comment: This question might be better on serverfault, but is there a reason why your replication agent couldn't handle it?  You're going to need some sort of replication policy between the servers anyway, is there a reason why it couldn't do it?

Comment: yeh.. I guess if it was stored in the db that'll work for now... sounds very fugly...

Answer (score 0):

I might have the app edit the contents of robots.txt and have the user input saved to a database. Then at certain intervals, have a background process pull the latest from the DB and push to your servers.

Comment: yeh.. this is what I'm trying to avoid... I dont' like the fact that I'm having to push updates to the servers...

Comment: well somehow, it has to end up in the robots.txt file on the server

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to have the reverse proxy that is doing your load balancing treat robots.txt differently. You could serve it directly from the reverse-proxy or have all requests for that file go to a single server. It makes a lot of sense since robots.txt is going to be required relatively infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're home on this yet.  If so ignore. (UPDATE: I see a note to your original post, but this may be useful reagrdless.)

If you **mapped a call** to robots.txt to an **http-handler or similar**, you can generate the response from say a dB.

Answer (score 0):

serve it via whatever dynamic content generation you are using. its just a file . nothing special.